# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick from Texview click

Tags: java, android

I started using Firebase (Database and Auth). I am trying to sign up from the app, but it crashes when I click "Done" TextView to register.

```
  E/UncaughtException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:389)
                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22433)
                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6176)
                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
                      Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384)
                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637) 
                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22433) 
                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6176) 
                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888) 
                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778) 
                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.TextView.getText()' on a null object reference
                         at com.example.supdude.appcomidita.registroUsuarios.onClick(registroUsuarios.java:65)
                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384) 
                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637) 
                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22433) 
                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6176) 
                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888) 
                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778) 
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.supdude.appcomidita, PID: 11899
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:389)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22433)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6176)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
                   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22433) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6176) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778) 
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.TextView.getText()' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.supdude.appcomidita.registroUsuarios.onClick(registroUsuarios.java:65)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384) 
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22433) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6176) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
```

This is the Onclick method

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    int idSelec= grupoRadio.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    sexo= findViewById(idSelec);
    String sex= sexo.getText().toString();
    String correo= corr.getText().toString();
    String pass=contra.getText().toString().trim();

                switch ( v.getId() ){

                    case R.id.hecho_RU:
                        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(correo,pass).addOnCompleteListener
                                (registroUsuarios.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                               if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                                    Toast.makeText(registroUsuarios.this, "Ha ocurrido un error al registrarse, inténtalo de nuevo más tarde", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }else{
                                   String nombre= nomb.getText().toString();
                                   String apellido=apell.getText().toString();
                                   String mail=corr.getText().toString();
                                   int telefono=Integer.parseInt(tel.getText().toString());
                                   String sex= sexo.getText().toString();
                                   String id_usuario = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                                   DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Usuarios").child(id_usuario);
                                   Map nuevoMapa = new HashMap();
                                   nuevoMapa.put("Nombre" ,nombre);
                                   nuevoMapa.put("Apellido" ,apellido);
                                   nuevoMapa.put("Correo" ,mail);
                                   nuevoMapa.put("Telefono" ,telefono);
                                   nuevoMapa.put("Sexo" ,sex);
                                   dbRef.setValue(nuevoMapa);
                                   startActivity(new Intent (registroUsuarios.this,login.class));
                               }
                            }
                        });
                        break;
                    case R.id.atrasRU:
                        finish();
                        break;


                }
}
```

When i had a lot of trouble with dependencies, but everything was pretty well.
After some modifications, the create user task from firebase wasn't successful doesn't even know why

Comment: One of your `TextView` widgets is `null`. See line 65 of `registroUsuarios.java` to determine which `TextView` that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make some change below code remove from onclick and i hope you set setonclick list on textview..like below code..

```
        textView=findViewById(R.id.textview);
    textView.setOnClickListener(this);




int idSelec= grupoRadio.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
sexo= findViewById(idSelec);
String sex= sexo.getText().toString();
String correo= corr.getText().toString();
String pass=contra.getText().toString().trim();
```

Comment: and take hall code into one method and call only method onclick event.

Comment: i feel so stupid, it's the second time that happens, thanks for the help